# Removing Duplicates from a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I had some help earlier on another post to remove the file extension in my dropdown list.  I now need to remove duplicates.  This is the current before and after:

Before:

```
video-1.mp4
video-1.ogv
video-1.webm
```

After: (Current code)

```
video-1
video-1
video-1
```

What I want:

```
video-1
```

Here is my code behind:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      BindGrid();
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
      List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
      foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
      {
        var item = new ListItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath), filePath);
        if (!files.Contains(item))
          files.Add(item);
      }

      DropDownList1.DataSource = files;
      DropDownList1.DataTextField = "";
      DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";
      DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
  }
```

Comment: But, which filePath would be in the ListItem value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to keep the `filePath` (at least for some of the files) and store it as the value of the `ListItem` as shown by your code.

You can use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> filenames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    var file_name_without_extension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

    if(filenames.ContainsKey(file_name_without_extension))
        continue;

    filenames.Add(file_name_without_extension, filePath);
}

List<ListItem> files = filenames.Select(x => new ListItem(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the duplicate file name in my dropdown list

Answer (score 1):

LINQ's extension method `.Distinct()` will help. You may need to manually add `using System.Linq;`

Don't forget that it will return new collection without duplict elements instead of modifying current one.

Comment: A little more help were to place in the above code would be very helpful.  I have tried a few things but cannot find the correct place to use it.

Comment: Before setting DataSource, call files = files.Distinct();